# Can I add rows to a Google Drive spreadhseet from a local text file?

Tags: dropbox, google-spreadsheets

Is there a way to automatically add rows to a Google spreadsheet documents by editing a local text file?

Maybe via DropBox or [GoogleCL](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/)?

Comment: Can you give me some feedback on the answer I gave?

Comment: Sorry and thank you, I was travelling at the time of your answer and I didn't get to check your #2 solution. Also now I see my question was not perfectly articulated (I added *automatically* just now). My point being that I'd like to only touch the local csv file (and possibly terminal) so I don't need to access/log in the google drive repository itself.

Answer (score 0):

The following choices can be made:

1. import the local CSV file into a separate sheet and copy the imported rows into the desired place
2. Write a script that does it for you. I was about to prepare the example myself, but there's no need to. The following link will explain in detail what to do: [add data via CSV file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section2)

Comment: both solutions imply operating on the spreadsheet itself, they're not automatic (just working locally) - it's my bad I wasn't specific enough while writing the question.